# Showing user image for custom comments created in a view

Tags: 7, views, users, comments

I am using a Drupal view for displaying comments.

I have the show: in the format field set to comments.
Therefore I won't be able to add extra fields in the field's section.

I have a custom URL where I show the contents of a node along with its comments and a comment box which I have custom coded.

How can I add a user image along with my comments?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a "Relationship" to the comment author, and then add the user picture from the updated field list.